# how to parse with multiple delimiters

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

I have lines such as this:

```
package:/data/app/com.bskyb.skynews.android-XZdcB7swzPqeBcgUp2P0JQ==/base.apk=com.bskyb.skynews.android
```

Note the two "=".  The "=" is the delimiter but sometimes there can be 1..n "=".

How can I parse using awk, must be awk, so that I can obtain
1. the element after "package:" up to and including the LAST "=" and then 2. the element that follows the last "=".

So using above I would get

1. `/data/app/com.bskyb.skynews.android-XZdcB7swzPqeBcgUp2P0JQ=`
2. `/base.apk=com.bskyb.skynews.android`

Comment: Your description says 'up to and including the last `=`', but your first output doesn't include the second `=` in the `==`, and in any case there's another `=` after that in the input.  Your question isn't clear to me, yet — your shown output doesn't match your described output.

Answer (score 2):

with `GNU` awk you can replicate `sed` substitute with capture.

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/.*:([^=]+=?)=(.*)/,"\\1\n\\2", 1)}' file

/data/app/com.bskyb.skynews.android-XZdcB7swzPqeBcgUp2P0JQ=
/base.apk=com.bskyb.skynews.android
```

Comment: You should mention that requires gawk.

Comment: thank you. worked perfectly although I dont understand it.

Comment: it's all in the regex.